# FIWARE Object Storage "no tenants available"

Tags: fiware, openstack-swift

When using the Object Storage GE node.js connector implementation from https://github.com/arvidkahl/fiware-object-storage we encounter the problem "no tenants available". We tested with two different community accounts where we first set up an object container within the fiware cloud. 
We are able to Receive an Auth Token and get a connection established message, but then we do not get the tenant ID i think. has anyone experienced something like that and can help or give us a better understanding of what is going wrong here?

we installed the fiware-object-storage with npm install fiware-object-storage.

this is our connection code:

```
var fiwareObjectStorageConfig = {
auth      : conf.fiware.auth_url,            // IP of the Auth Services, likely "cloud.lab.fi-ware.org"
url       : conf.fiware.object_storage_url,  // IP of the Object Storage GE -> "cloud.lab.fi-ware.org"
user      : conf.fiware.user,              // Your FIWARE account email
password  : conf.fiware.password,            // Your FIWARE account password.. i know.. no comment.
container : conf.fiware.container            // Whatever container you want to connect to
};

var fiwareObjectStorage = require('fiware-object-storage');

fios = fiwareObjectStorage(fiwareObjectStorageConfig);

fios.connectToObjectStorage(function() {
    console.log(fios.getFileList());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This library is a third party library and it is not an official FIWARE implementation.

As you said, there is a problem with this library. I have tested and it needs some fixes. I could not reproduce your error with my account but I have another one while getting file list.

The best option is waiting for their developers to improve that simple library like select Tenant in config file. By now it takes the first tenant on the list.

This is my config file to access Spain2 object store:

```
fiwareObjectStorageConfig = {
  url       : '172.32.0.144',
  auth      : 'cloud.lab.fi-ware.org',
  container : 'myContainer',
  user      : "",      // Your FIWARE account email
  password  : ""           // Your FIWARE account password.
};
```

Comment: Yeah, it was built as a single-purpose library. But there has been a pull request for this issue already - and I merged it. Tenant selection sounds like another candidate.